# Empty Request.Form using $http angular to post

Tags: c#, angularjs

Having trouble getting my from data out of Request in C#. What I have is angular $http posting to a proxy api. Problem is that Request.Form is empty; same goes for Request.InputStream.

Angular:

```
$http({
                method: "POST",
                url: '/apiproxy/projects/' + data.Project.Id + '/recruiting-groups',
                data: angular.toJson(group, false)
            });
```

C#:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string pathInfo)
        {
            var url = Settings.GetValue<string>("QualService") + "/" + pathInfo + "?" + Request.QueryString;


            //Get stuff from the back end
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " +
                                                                  Convert.ToBase64String(
                                                                      Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                                                                          "x:{0}".Fmt(UserSession.ApiKey)));


                try
                {
                    var responseBytes = Request.HttpMethod == "POST" ? client.UploadValues(url, Request.Form) : client.DownloadData(url);

                    var result = new ContentResult();
                    result.Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
                    result.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    result.ContentType = "application/json";
                    return result;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.Error("Error while proxying to the API:  ", e);
                }
            }

            return Json(false);
        }
```

When I look at network tab in chrome I can see the data being passed:
[image: PostedData]

No matter what though Request.Form is null. And for that matter Request.InputStream is empty. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding one of the following header types:

application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data